# Understanding hierarchy of tracking requests through Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I would like to understand better tracking requests and responses, such as actions on cookies, cache, etc (read, write, update).

Compared to other tools, like Lightbeam, I am particularly interested in understanding who is 3rd party to whom. So I want to understand the hierarchy of requests (this one triggers this other one).

I have tried using Chrome dev tools to understand this, but haven't quite figured it out. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while hovering over a request to view its initiator and dependencies.

See [View initiator and dependencies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#initiators-dependencies).

Of course, the Initiator column in the Network panel's table also tells you a request's initiator.

Comment: Full disclosure: you are the awesome Technical Writer at Google who wrote the Dev Tools guide. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this ;)

Comment: Since you are here, I might as well say this: maybe there could be a way to prune the whole tree/forest of requests at a specific one (i.e. only initiators and dependencies, say through the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key); also, maybe there could be a way to present these request dependencies in a nested fashion.